# Trouble installing xylib in Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Any help would be appreciated!

I have obtained the xylib library from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xylib-py/ , and I have added the SWIG and boost libraries to Anaconda as specified by the website. However, I am not successful in installing the xylib package into Anaconda despite using methods that were suggested.

Methods I have tried to install the xylib package that has failed so far:

1) conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/mw xylib

2) pip install setup.py

Image link: https://imgur.com/visebt9

3) conda install setup.py

Image link: https://imgur.com/eXHVI3u

4) python setup.py install

Image link: https://imgur.com/U3fAwbL

Currently using Windows 10, Anaconda3 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

1) would work on a platform for which the repository has packages -- this conda repository has no packages for Windows.

2) and 3) are incorrect -- you have `setup.py` in place of package name

4) is good, but the compiler complains that it cannot find a header from Boost.
Are you sure you added Boost libraries to Anaconda? Where are the header files, such as `boost\shared_ptr.hpp`? The compiler checks `...\Anaconda3\include` but apparently the headers are not there.